# ubuntu 16 iphone 5s sync

Tags: sync, banshee, iphone

Hi I'm having issues while trying to sync iphone 5s with ubuntu 16. The thing is that ubuntu sees the iphone in the filesystem, but neither rhytmbox nor banshee can even see it. I tried to plug in iphone unlocked(could be security problem) but what I achieved was that both rhytmbox and banshee crashed when I launched them. I have libimobiledevice6 installed to the newest version, same with banshee, please help!